# Is there a Flutter clean command to clean only specific files?

Tags: flutter

I'm facing this problem, anytime I run `flutter clean` it deletes some files that speed up my build process, and I end up waiting a long time for my flutter app to build. I need a way to only clean files I specifically asked to be cleaned. Does a command like that exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in flutter command exist that can do that. `flutter clean` deletes the build/ and .dart_tool/ directories. If you need something else, it's just easiest to write your own script that deletes what you want.

In common *nix environments you could do something like:
`rm !("filename1"|"filename2")` which would deletes files i a directory except `filename1` and `filename2`

or check e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some for more alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Flutter Web app using Firebase and require environment variables. There is an `.env` file in the `functions` directory (I'm using [Dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) here). This file includes an ENVIRONMENT variable set to `staging` or `production` depending on what I'm working on. The Flutter frontend gets its environment variables from this file as well using the [Envied](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) package. This requires an Env class in the `web_flutter/env` directory and a generated `env.g.dart` file that is not committed to the repo. I made a Make command `make clean-flutter-env` that deletes and regenerates the Flutter files `env.g.dart` and `env.envied.g.part` to update/use the environment variables in the frontend (see the Make commands below for details).

Using Make I'm running:

```
clean-flutter-env: clean-env-cache generate-env
clean-flutter-env: |
    rm web_flutter/.dart_tool/build/generated/web_flutter/lib/env/*.g.part web_flutter/lib/env/*g.dart
generate-env: |
    cd web_flutter && dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

So it's possible to do a targeted cache clean and only build what's needed.